# How can I only show rows common with another dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to only show rows of a pandas dataframe that have a have the first column in common with another row in another dataframe. Here's my code:

```
sen_race.iloc(sen_race['Precinct'] == mi4['Precinct'])
```

Here are photos of the dataframes if they're helpful:

mi4 dataframe: https://ibb.co/2qFMq4v

sen_race dataframe: https://ibb.co/y4qBHG1

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-7695709c5335> in <module>
----> 1 sen_race.iloc(sen_race['Precinct'] == mi4['Precinct'])

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py in new_method(self, other)
     62         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     63 
---> 64         return method(self, other)
     65 
     66     return new_method

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in wrapper(self, other)
    519 
    520         if isinstance(other, ABCSeries) and not self._indexed_same(other):
--> 521             raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
    522 
    523         lvalues = extract_array(self, extract_numpy=True)

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Why isn't it working?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: one dataframe has 150 rows and the others have 60 rows so a column based search will not work. You can do a merge though `sen_race.merge(mi4['Precinct'], on='Precinct')` since the default merge type is an "inner" join, it will only show rows where Precinct is in common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work. from [merge documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
sen_race.merge(mi4['Precinct'], on='Precinct', how='inner')
```

However, there is a major caveat, that the precincts are unique. If df 1 has more than one precinct in common, it will print both rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to filter the results then you can use:

```
df = sen_race[sen_race['Precinct'].isin(mi4['Precinct'])]
```